# Как взаимодействовать с DOM деревом через расширение для CHROME?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chrome-extension

Пишу свое первое расширение для хрома, надо по работе.

**В расширении есть:** текстовое поле и кнопка, при нажатии на кнопку, должен произойти поиск того, что пользователь написал в текстовое поле на странице ( аналог ctrl+f). Но, пишу я это для того, что поиск нужен по большому меню (как аккардион), которое по умолчанию скрыто (свернуто), соответственно пока не развернешь, поиск не возможен.

**Задача плагина:** развернуть это древо и найти в нем то, что написано в текстовое поле.

**Создал файлы:**

1. index.html - тело плагина
2. jquery.js - подключается библиотека jquery
3. manifest.json - собственно файл манифест
4. popup.js - сам скрипт jq который должен менять DOM

Сам сайт мне не доступен, все операции только на стороне клиента, поэтому и пишу плагин.

В **manifest.json** у меня вот что:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "ИМЯ ПЛАГИНА",
    "description": "Можно модули поискать. Удобно.Наверное...",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "css": ["css.css"],
      "matches": ["урл.сайта"],
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html",
      "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"]
    }
 }
```

Прошелся Firebagом по тому сайту, нашел стиль отвечающий за свернуть/развернуть меню:

```
.ng-hide {
    display:none !important
}
```

Соответственно нужно что-бы эти классы было видно

В **popup.js** сделал вот так :(с предвкушением, что ничего из этого не выйдет)

```
$('ng-hide').css({'display: block !important'});
```

и ничего не вышло, взаимодействия с DOM нет.

Подскажите, как мне заставить браузер изменять объекты DOM дерева через плагин.

Comment: вы написали селектор который ничего вам не вернет. У вас класс `.ng-hide`, так и создавайте селектор `$('.ng-hide')`

Answer (score 2):

Popup расширения - это отдельная страница, которая с вкладками может общатся единственным способом - через content_script, который подгружается непосредственно в страницу, которая загружена во вкладке.

Вам нужно сделать как то так:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ИМЯ ПЛАГИНА",
    "description": "Можно модули поискать. Удобно.Наверное...",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "css": ["css.css"],
      "matches": ["урл.сайта"],
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html",
      "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"]
    },


    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["урл.сайта*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "content_script.js"]
    }]
 }
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    $('.ng-hide').css({'display: block !important'});
});
```

**popup.js**

```
// Можно повесить на клик или на onload
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, tab => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {/*Тут можно передать в content script*/}, function sendResponse(response){
            // Это callback, который можно вызвать из content_script
        });
    });
```